# 'in search for/of true love?'

Tags: prepositions

I need to update my fb status:

> in search **for** true love

or

> in search **of** true love

Which one is grammatically correct ?

Comment: *in search **of** true love* is idiomatic. Otherwise, both prepositions are perfectly grammatical. They may have subtly different connotations but no grammatical difference.

Comment: @Kris so what is the correct sentence that suits for my requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

In search of true love is grammatically correct.

Comment: Not a problem, Hector!

Comment: Why do you think so? Anything in support?

Comment: Yes. 'In search of' is  the correct idiomatic form.  In search for is used mainly in News Headlines . When you are looking for somethin, you always say - "Ïn search of"

Answer (score -1):

In search for denotes a project, whereas in search of denotes a purpose.

e.g. Captain Smollett and their crew set out... on a search for buried treasure

The last few years of his life were spent in travelling from place to place in search of health.

Comment: specify a reason or an example ??

Comment: Maybe you are right. However, you need to show that through something in support.